Increase spacing in ggplot legend items
I have two shapefiles of a Country, one containing the geometry of the municipalities and the other regarding the border of the regions of the country. I have to plot the country with the municipalities filled by a variable, and i managed to do it with the following code:
cols <- c("orange", "red", "chartreuse4", "lightblue", "white")

municipalities %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = `Zone`), color = NA) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = cols,
    name = element_blank(),
    guide = guide_legend(
      keyheight = unit(6, units = "mm"),
      keywidth = unit(15, units = "mm"),
      label.position = "right",
      override.aes = list(colour = "black"),
      ncol = 3
    ),
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.4, 0.05),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
    plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic", size = 14, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = 6))
  ) +
  geom_sf(data = regions, linewidth = 0.1, color = "black", fill = NA)

However, this code produces the following output:

I want to increase the spacing between the legend items, both vertical and horizontal spacing.
I tried all the possible combinations adding
guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE))

or
theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(1.5, "cm"))

but the result is that not only the spacing doesn't change, but also it changes the shape of the rectangles in the legend (which i want to keep) in the classical square of the default ggplot legend, like this:

Anyone knows how to add horizontal and vertical spacing between the items of the legend keeping the rectangles of the first image?
Thanks in advance!

Legend spacing has been updated in ggplot2 3.5.0, see my answer here for an explanation. TL;DR: use legend.key.spacing.{x/y} instead.
